# PDFsharp image to XImage

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdfsharp

I created a barcode as an image in my ASP.NET MVC app.

```
BarcodeLib.Barcode barcode = new BarcodeLib.Barcode()                   
{                        
    IncludeLabel = false,
    Alignment = AlignmentPositions.LEFT,
    Width = element.BarcodeWidth,
    Height = element.BarcodeHeight,
    RotateFlipType = RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipNone,
    BackColor = Color.Transparent,
    ForeColor = Color.Black,
    ImageFormat = System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png
 };
```

This will create a barcode with the BarcodeLib.
How do I convert it to an XImage of PDFsharp?

```
Image img = barcode.Encode(TYPE.CODE128, "123456789");
gfx.DrawImage(xImage, 0, 0, 100, 100);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solved it this way:

```
Image img = barcode.Encode(TYPE.CODE128, Name); // this is the image

MemoryStream strm = new MemoryStream();
img.Save(strm, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

XImage xfoto = XImage.FromStream(strm);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you use the GDI build of PDFsharp then you can call the `XImage.FromImage` method.

With any build of PDFsharp you can write an PNG image to a MemoryStream and then get an XImage from that MemoryStream.

Comment: There is also `XImage.FromStream`, so you can add images created in a MemoryStream. You'll need version 1.5 for that.

Answer (score 3):

Actually method had been changed in .net core version. It takes Func as parameter. Attention please: It's unofficial version for .net core.

```
XImage xImage = XImage.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(yourByte[]));
```

Comment: Are you sure? Please look at the method, after then we can discuss about that

Comment: Looks like an inofficial port of PDFsharp (I don't know which). Most likely it didn't exist in 2017 when the question was asked. Not useful to illustrate special extensions of special ports without clearly identifying the port they belong to.

Comment: That's right, It's an unofficial but this is so useful for .net core otherwise you have to change most of things. So please correct your scoring.

Answer (score 1):

Also,
If you know image path you can use that

```
XImage xImage = XImage.FromFile(imagePath)
```